# Cascade two drop down lists based on primary drop down list

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a table with three values, Division, Unit, Site and three drop down lists. A Division may have both Units and Sites others may have only Units or only Sites.
I can make a cascade drop down for Division and Unit or Site but not for all three values
I work with asp.net and C# and stored procedures for SQL table

I tried to use the method for a simple cascade drop down but I get an error

System.ArgumentException: 'The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection.'

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;


namespace WAPReview
{
    public partial class AddData : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                PopulateDivisionDropDownList();
            }
        }

        private DataSet GetData(string SPName, SqlParameter SPParameter)
        {
            string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString1"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SPName, con);
            da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            if (SPParameter != null)
            {
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(SPParameter);
            }
            DataSet DS = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(DS);
            return DS;
        }

        private void PopulateDivisionDropDownList()
        {
            ddlDivision.DataSource = GetData("Division", null);
            ddlDivision.DataBind();

            ListItem liDivision = new ListItem("Select Division", "-1");
            ddlDivision.Items.Insert(0, liDivision);

            ListItem liUnit = new ListItem("Select Unit", "-1");
            ddlUnit.Items.Insert(0, liUnit);

            ListItem liSite = new ListItem("Select Site", "-1");
            ddlSite.Items.Insert(0, liSite);

            ddlUnit.Enabled = false;
            ddlSite.Enabled = false;
        }
        protected void ddlDivision_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ddlDivision.SelectedValue == "-1")
            {
                ddlUnit.SelectedIndex = 0;
                ddlUnit.Enabled = false;
                ddlSite.SelectedIndex = 0;
                ddlSite.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                ddlUnit.Enabled = true;
                ddlSite.Enabled = true;

                SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@Division",
                    Value = ddlDivision.SelectedValue
                };

                ddlUnit.DataSource = GetData("Unit", parameter);
                ddlUnit.DataBind();

                ddlSite.DataSource = GetData("Site", parameter);
                ddlSite.DataBind();

                ListItem liUnit = new ListItem("Select Unit", "-1");
                ddlUnit.Items.Insert(0, liUnit);

                ListItem liSite = new ListItem("Select Unit", "-1");
                ddlSite.Items.Insert(0, liSite);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I choose the Division I am expecting to have the corespondent Unit and/or Sites displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error is explaining, you are using the variable *parameter* in two distinct SqlCommands (the two calls to the function *GetData*).

Try changing the parameter of the *GetData* function to feed directly the ddlDivision.SelectedValue and create the SqlParameter inside the function: it will work as a charm!

```
private DataSet GetData(string SPName, object selectedDivision)
    {
        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString1"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SPName, con);
        da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        if (selectedDivision != null)
        {
            SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@Division",
                    Value = selectedDivision
                };

            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(parameter);
        }

        DataSet DS = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(DS);
        return DS;
    }
```

Comment: I get this error System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Procedure Division has no parameters and arguments were supplied.'

Comment: I am sorry I did not noticed that the parameter was only provided in some cases. Check the updated code.

Comment: ddlUnit.DataSource = GetDataDivision("Unit", parameter); parameter does not exist. SelectedIndexChange function

Comment: You should use ddlUnit.DataSource = GetData("Unit", ddlDivision.SelectedValue) instead

Comment: It is Ok, it was my mistake, things are Ok, thank you very much